# How to set infinite scroll in OJET Table?

Tags: oracle-jet

I am using OJET framework's `oj-table` component. The structure of the table looks as below:

```js
    protected render(): VComponent.VNode {
    return (
      <div>
        <oj-table
          id="table"
          aria-label="Lists"
          selectionMode={this.selectedSelectionMode}
          data={this.dataSource}
          columns={this.columns}
          class="oj-bg-neutral-0"
        ></oj-table> 
      </div>
    )};
```

Can someone please help on how I can set the scrolling as infinite-scroll? There should be a way in which the records should load as we scroll in the table. I am new to OJET framework and do not have much idea how we can achieve this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of documentation re-read I found an answer for this issue.
In oracle-jet, they have added a property to the `<oj-table>` called `scrollPolicy`.

I have modified the code as below with scrollPolicy

```js
   protected render(): VComponent.VNode {
      return (
          <div>
              <oj-table
               id="table"
               aria-label="Lists"
               selectionMode={this.selectedSelectionMode}
               data={this.dataSource}
               scrollPolicy="loadAll"
               columns={this.columns}
               class="oj-bg-neutral-0"
              ></oj-table> 
          </div>
       )};
```

Now the dataSource fetches more records as I reach to the end of the table. This is a cool feature and helped me reduce my first payload size. Posting it here so that it can help someone who got stuck on this. Cheers!!